# How to generate the DB script by query. (NOT GUI)

Tags: sql-server

I tried to generate the script by query because I want create easily and same settings. I checked MSdoc but there is no method.

I use SSMS v17.6, SQLServer2016(SP2)  on WindowsServer2012 R2 Standard.

By the GUI, DB right click=>Task=>generate scripts=>select database objects and set some settings.
I want to generate by query.

Comment: You're right - there is no single "method". This is a hugely complicated coding task that requires advanced skill in tsql. You mention no language, but you can use the [SMO package](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/server-management-objects-smo/overview-smo?view=sql-server-2017) to do this - though it is quite complex. SSDT can be useful as well as backup/restore tsql commands.

Answer (score 0):

You can follow below steps to automate the creation of a database.

1. First export the database as a dapac using [Export Data Tier Application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/data-tier-applications/export-a-data-tier-application?view=sql-server-2017)
2. Install SQLPackage.exe in the environment where you are planning to carry out the deployment. You can download [sqlpackage.exe download path](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sqlpackage-download?view=sql-server-2017) . It will be used to automate the generation of scripts from DACPAC.
3. Once you have the DACPAC of the database, you can publish the same to any environment. The caveat is, Sqlpackage.exe generates incremental script, comparing against the target datatbase. If you want complete CREATE script, then you can point against any empty database or system database like master to generate incremental CREATE scripts(here it will be complete database script, as target is empty database). The generated script will be present in the output path (here, it is C:\temp)

> **Note:** we are setting parameter (DropObjectsNotInSource to false), to avoid generation of drop objects of the target database, which are
>   missing in source DACPAC.

```
"<Path>\SqlPackage.exe"
/Action:script
/SourceFile:“<Path>\Database.dacpac” 
/TargetDatabaseName:master
/TargetServerName:"localhost"
/OutputPath:C:\temp
/p:DropObjectsNotInSource:false
```

**UPDATE**

I see that, now there is a tool mssql-scripter(currently in preview) to carry out the same activity of Generate Scripts wizard of SQL Server Management Studio. You can see about the tool here: https://github.com/Microsoft/mssql-scripter